# How would you invoke an event with reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, class, events, event-handling

Say I have a class just for specifying C# events and I pass this class around my application.

```
public class MyEvents
{
    public event MyEventHandler OnBeforeSomeAction;
    public event MyEventHandler OnSomeAction;
}
```

In order to invoke these events the invocation has to come from within the class itself. The easy way to let other classes trigger these events as `MyEvents` gets passed around the application would be to create public trigger functions.

```
public class MyEvents
{
    public event MyEventHandler OnBeforeSomeAction;
    public event MyEventHandler OnSomeAction;

    public void TriggerOnBeforeSomeAction()
    {
        OnBeforeSomeAction();
    }

    public void TriggerOnSomeAction()
    {
        OnSomeAction();
    }
}
```

However, if there are many events on this class then there would also have to be many trigger methods. Would there be a way to get the event using reflection and trigger it? Something like this:

```
public class MyEvents
{
    public event MyEventHandler OnBeforeSomeAction;
    public event MyEventHandler OnSomeAction;

    public void TriggerEvent(string eventName)
    {
        var event = // some magic reflection.
        event.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible, yes, should you do it, probably not.  Passing the event as a string is likely to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Let me clarify that I am not concerned with what is correct or incorrect with regard to best practices. I simply want to know how to accomplish this, not whether or not I should.

Comment: So you're specifically not looking for answers that solve your actual problem.  * walks away*.

Comment: I'm looking for answers that answer my exact question. This isn't codereview.stackexchange.com. It's stackoverflow.com. I am aware that what I am asking is not a best practice; that is really all you can ask for when you insist on telling someone what they should and should not do.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CSharpMessenger_Extended)

Comment: @L.B That does look interesting. I believe that is what I am trying to achieve. I will investigate further.

Comment: Can you guarantee that you will *always* use a field-like event? If not, you can't guarantee to do it with reflection at all. (Why not just remove the `event` keyword, to make them public fields, if you've already said goodbye to good practice? Might as well make it simple...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what you want - taken from [this fantastic page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/44b0d573-5c53-47b0-8e85-6056cbae95b0)....

```
    public void TriggerEvent(string handler, EventArgs e)
    {
        MulticastDelegate eventDelegate =
              (MulticastDelegate)this.GetType().GetField(handler,
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this);

        Delegate[] delegates = eventDelegate.GetInvocationList();

        foreach (Delegate dlg in delegates)
        {
            dlg.Method.Invoke(dlg.Target, new object[] { this, e });
        } 
    }
```